# What happens if you don't register your local address when visiting Germany?

Tags: schengen-visas

As a U.S. citizen on a tourist visa or no visa what happens if you don't register your local address and get caught? What actually happens in practice if anyone has first hand experience?

---

What about apartment rentals. Do landlords/owners ever require to show proof of registration?

Comment: Is the local address a rental or a hotel(s)?

Comment: @Traveller rental or long term housing.

Comment: To answer your actual question: "What actually happens in practice..."  Nothing.

Comment: @Fattie if you have personal experience or a source for that comment, it should be an answer.

Comment: @phoog - I absolutely encourage you to add such a comment, to every comment equally worthy of such a comment, in - say - all of this week's posts  :)

Comment: @user5389726598465: Given this clarification, I'm not sire about whether this question is more suited for [expats.se].

Comment: @Fattie: Depends on the place. Some cities are quick at fining the landlord who will then be accordingly disgruntled with their tenant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to accurately answer this question, we need more information, in particular: for how long is a U.S. citizen on a tourist visa or no visa going to stay in Germany?

According to [Reporting presence for short stays](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/residence/documents-formalities/reporting-presence/germany/index_en.htm):

> If you are moving into an apartment or a house, for up to 3 months, there is no obligation to notify the registration authority.

If you stay for more than 3 months, didn't register your local address within the predefined deadline, get caught, and if there are no particular reasons preventing you from registering within the statutory time limit, [you should pay a fine that can be up to € 500](https://www.welt.de/finanzen/immobilien/article139207592/Neues-Gesetz-soll-Adressenmissbrauch-verhindern.html)

I have never met a landlord that required to show proof of registration. However, this is just my personal experience.